# Polynomial ring: $X$ capital or small letters

Tags: abstract-algebra, soft-question

For a polynomial ring $F[X]$ where $F$ is a field, what is the usual convention for capital or small letters for $X$?

Q1) I.e., should it be $F[X]$ or $F[x]$?

I guess theoretically it doesn't matter, just curious to know what is the usual convention.

Q2) Also, just curious why when it comes to polynomial rings, people suddenly use capital letters to denote polynomials, e.g. $X^2+1$, instead of $x^2+1$ which is more common in other branches of math? Is there a deep reason?

This trivial question has been bugging me for some time, asking it now that I remember it.

Thanks.

Comment: There are pedagogical reasons for using capital letters for formal polynomials, to distinguish them from functions.

Comment: We usually use the uppercase $X$ to distinguish the formal polynomial from the lowercase $x$, which traditionally denotes a number (or the polynomial function $x \mapsto x$).

Comment: Some authors have notational conventions, some don't. Use whatever works best in your context.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The reason for the capital letters notation, as used by *Bourbaki*, for instance, is to insist on the fact a polynomial is *not* a polynomial function.

A polynomial with coefficients in a commutative ring $R$ is merely a  sequence of coefficients in $R$, eventually ending in $0$s, endowed with two operations, $+$ and $\times$.

Thus the *indeterminate* $X$ is but the sequence $(0,1,0,0,0,\dots)$. It happens that the operations are designed so that $X^2=(0,0,1,0,0,\dots)$, $(X^3=(0,0,0,1,0,\dots)$ and so on. Even $1=(1,0,0,0,0,\dots)=X^0$.

To each polynomial $P(X)\in R[X]$ one associates a *polynomial function* one often denotes with the same name
\begin{align*}
P\colon R&\longrightarrow R\\
x&\longmapsto P(x)
\end{align*}
substituting the element $x$ of $R$ to each occurrence of the indeterminate $X$.

The correspondence polynomial-polynomial function is not necessarily injective, except on an infinite integral domain. For instance, in the field $\mathbf F_p$, the polynomial function associated to the non-zero polynomial  $X^p-X$ is the $0$ function (this is a way of formulating *Little Fermat*).

Comment: Very interesting. Learnt something new.

Comment: It should be *emphasized* that this convention is very far from being universal.

Comment: @Bill Dubuque: Which convention do you mean? Capital letters for indeterminates?

Comment: I see only one convention mentioned in your answer. Notation widely varies, so no convention can be considered to be standard.